# Under what cases is the Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) operator nilpotent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, quantization, superalgebra

It is understood that when we deal with gauge algebras which close on-shell only after using equations of motion or where the space-time is curved, we can no longer just do away with [BRST quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRST_formalism). We have to use the [BV formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) and then quantize the theory.

Is the BV operator nilpotent even off-shell? What similarities and differences are there between BRST charge (nilpotent on-shell) and the BV operator( also called BV Laplacian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. On one hand, traditionally, the [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) operator $\Delta$ in Lagrangian BRST formulation encodes geometric data of the antisymplectic phase space for the model, specifically the antisymplectic structure [i.e. the so-called antibracket $(\cdot,\cdot)$, or odd Poisson bracket] and a path integral volume density $\rho$. The BV operator $\Delta f$ on a function $f$ is usually taken to be (proportional to) the $\rho$-divergence$^1$ of the Hamiltonian vector field $(f,\cdot)$, which makes it a differential operator of second order known as the *odd Laplacian.* The off-shell nilpotency 
   $$\Delta^2~=~0\tag{1}$$
   of $\Delta$ encodes a compatibility condition$^2$ between the antibracket $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and the path integral measure density $\rho$.
2. On the other hand, there is the the quantum master action $W$, which is built from the original action, the original gauge symmetry, auxiliary fields and antifields using the BV recipe/cookbook, in such a way that it satisfies 
   the quantum master equation 
   $$ \Delta e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}W}~=~0\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad\frac{1}{2}(W,W)~=~i\hbar\Delta W \tag{2}$$
   off-shell. The quantum BRST operator is defined as
   $$\sigma~:=~(W,\cdot)-i\hbar\Delta \tag{3}$$
   The quantum BRST operator is nilpotent
   $$\sigma^2~=~0\tag{4}$$
   off-shell, due to eqs. (1)-(3).
3. Let us for completeness mention that there is also a Hamiltonian analogue to the Lagrangian BV formalism. This is known as Batalin-Fradkin-Vilkovisky (BFV) formalism. Here the BRST charge $Q$,
   which is Poisson nilpotent
   $$\{Q,Q\}_{PB}~=~0\tag{5}$$
   off-shell, generates the BRST transformation $\{Q,\cdot\}_{PB}$, which in turn is off-shell nilpotent, 
   $$\{Q,\{Q,\cdot\}_{PB}\}_{PB}~=~0\tag{6}$$
   due to eq. (5) and the Jacobi identity for the even Poisson bracket $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{PB}$.

--

$^1$ The [Liouville Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29) in symplectic geometry, which states that Hamiltonian vector fields are divergence-free, does *not* hold in antisymplectic geometry.

$^2$This compatibility condition for $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $\rho$ is e.g. satisfied for antisymplectic Darboux coordinates with $\rho=1$. There exist in the literature various generalizations that relax this compatibility condition.